# Golang Generate Unique Filename With Extension

Tags: go, temporary-files

I want to generate unique filenames in Golang with extensions.  Very much akin to ioutil.TempFile, which only takes prefixes.

This has been brought up many times in the forums https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/PHgye3Hm2_0 and the Go goes seem pretty intent on not adding that functionality to TempFile.

So what's the suggested way to handle this?  Should I just copy/paste the TempFile code and add in a suffix parameter?

Comment: Why is it important that you need a suffix?

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Go 1.16 (Feb 2021), you can use `os.CreateTemp`:

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   dirs := []string{"", "."}
   for _, dir := range dirs {
      f, err := os.CreateTemp(dir, "*.txt")
      if err != nil {
         panic(err)
      }
      defer f.Close()
      println(f.Name())
   }
}
```

Result:

```
C:\Windows\TEMP\163991747.txt
.\2499233563.txt
```

https://godocs.io/os#CreateTemp

Answer (score 7):

Update (2020: the original answer is from 2015)

As noted in [Lax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3997690/lax)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050527/6309), Go 1.11 (Apr. 2018) has changed  `TempFile` prefix to a pattern.

See [commit 191efbc](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/191efbc419d7e5dec842c20841f6f716da4b561d) from [CL 105675](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/105675/) after [issue 4896](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4896)

> Users of `TempFile` need to be able to supply the suffix, especially
>   when using operating systems that give semantic meaning to the
>   filename extension such as Windows.
>   Renaming the file to include an extension after the fact is insufficient as it could lead to race conditions.
>
> If the string given to `TempFile` includes a "`*`", the random string
>   replaces the "`*`".
>
> For example "`myname.*.bat`" will result in a random
>   filename such as "`myname.123456.bat`".
>
> If no "`*`' is included the
>   old behavior is retained, and the random digits are appended to the
>   end.
>
> If multiple "`*`" are included, the final one is replaced, thus
>   permitting a pathological programmer to create filenames such as
>   "`foo*.123456.bat`" but not "`foo.123456.*.bat`"

---

Original Answer (2015)

> Should I just copy/paste the TempFile code and add in a suffix parameter?

That would be one way.
Other way is to make a quick -- crude -- implementation, as in [this project](https://github.com/joncrlsn/fileutil/blob/5aac37a6ac963fd712b618b024d2eb14aa190958/fileutil.go#L98-L103):

```
// TempFileName generates a temporary filename for use in testing or whatever
func TempFileName(prefix, suffix string) string {
    randBytes := make([]byte, 16)
    rand.Read(randBytes)
    return filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), prefix+hex.EncodeToString(randBytes)+suffix)
}
```

As [James Henstridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/c) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005865/golang-generate-unique-filename-with-extension#comment44400866_28005931) below, this is a *crude* function:

> That function can return file names that already exist, for instance. Such an API should be creating the file by opening it with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` to ensure that no one else creates the file between deciding on the name and creating the file.

That crude function above illustrates only the use of [`rand.Read()`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read) to generate a filename.

But the other checks are all in [`io/ioutil/tempfile.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/ioutil/tempfile.go).
[3of3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130971/3of3) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005865/golang-generate-unique-filename-with-extension#comment44403134_28005865) to use a function in [`math.rand`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/)  instead of copying the [random number generator in `io/ioutil/tempfile.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c2c0bf77efef5fd0e1cdecb330a9d30de1509ff8/src/io/ioutil/tempfile.go#L22-L36).

Comment: You definitely need more than just that function.  That function can return file names that already exist, for instance.  Such an API should be creating the file by opening it with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` to ensure that no one else creates the file between deciding on the name and creating the file.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://github.com/tink-ab/tempfile. It's basically what the standard library supplies, but with support for both prefix and suffix.

Comment: Is it really worth it adding a new dependency to the code for a function that can be copied locally?

Comment: Moataz: Nothing is stopping you from copying it. I think that's a decision up to you.

Comment: ...however, remember that the repo will have a suite of tests which we are willing to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who would read this thread more recently, as of now (April 2020), `ioutil.TempFile` handles both prefix and suffix.

From its documentation:

> TempFile creates a new temporary file in the directory dir,
>   opens the file for reading and writing, and returns the resulting `*os.File`.
>   The filename is generated by taking pattern and adding a random
>   string to the end. If pattern includes a "`*`", the random string
>   replaces the last "`*`".

As such, passing "`prefix-*-suffix`" as the `pattern` argument would yield the expected behaviour.